# Sharing Java HTTP session with .Net

Tags: java, asp.net, cookies, spring-security, cas

We have one common Java Web application (A) which takes care of the login mechanism and it uses spring security. Later many other java web applications uses the Spring security context initialized by the common web application (A) and does not needs login again (SSO).

We are planning to achieve the SSO using CAS with Spring security.

The problem is we have another .Net web application which needs to use this common java web application (A) for login mechanism and SSO.

1) How can this integration be achieved ? 
2) How to share the user details with the .Net application ?
3) Is sharing cookie the only way ?
4) Would there be any problems in using cookies like reliability, security, etc ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

Why don't you use the .Net CAS client? and the new /p3/serviceValidate endpoint to push user attributes?